# Foundation 5 Keep Tooltip open

Tags: zurb-foundation

How can I keep the tooltip open with a "tap to close" option just like with mobile, but on the desktop? I was thinking about achieving this with an off-canvas menu, but I don't see how I could open the canvas vertically from that div, pushing everything down, instead of coming in from left or right. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I found the [hoverable drop down option](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html) to be satisfactory for my needs.

Comment: Ran into the same issue as you and the Foundation Dropdown was the answer for me too, thanks!